# My CodeIgniter PHP code cannot update the data

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the code like below, but when I update the data, the data is not updated but add new data in the database

How can I make updates / edit data and not add new data when saved?

Here I use CodeIgniter version 3.1.8, php version 7.2.4

model_anggota.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Model_anggota extends CI_model {
  public function getdata($key){
    $this->db->where('nama',$key);
    $hasil = $this->db->get('tb_anggota');
    return $hasil;
  }

  public function getupdate($key,$data){
    $this->db->where('nama',$key);
    $this->db->update('tb_anggota',$data);
  }

  public function getinsert($data){

    $this->db->insert('tb_anggota',$data);
  }

  public function getdelete($key){

    $this->db->where('nim',$key);
    $this->db->delete('tb_anggota');
  }
}
```

data_anggota.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Data_anggota extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->model_security->getsecurity();
        $isi['content'] = 'data_anggota/tampil_dataanggota';
    $isi['data'] = $this->db->get('tb_anggota');
        $this->load->view('tampilan_home',$isi);
    }

  public function tambah(){
    $this->model_security->getsecurity();
        $isi['content'] = 'data_anggota/form_tambahanggota';

        $this->load->view('tampilan_home',$isi);
  }

  public function edit(){
    $this->model_security->getsecurity();
        $isi['content'] = 'data_anggota/form_editanggota';
    $key = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $this->db->where('nim',$key);
    $query = $this->db->get('tb_anggota');
    if($query->num_rows()>0){
      foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
        $isi['nama'] = $row->nama;
        $isi['nim'] = $row->nim;
        $isi['jurusan'] = $row->jurusan;
        $isi['tempat_lahir'] = $row->tempat_lahir;
        $isi['tanggal_lahir'] = $row->tanggal_lahir;
        $isi['alamat'] = $row->alamat;
        $isi['agama'] = $row->agama;
        $isi['kelamin'] = $row->kelamin;
        $isi['angkatan'] = $row->angkatan;
        $isi['status'] = $row->status;
      }
    }
    $this->load->view('tampilan_home',$isi);
  }


  public function simpan(){
    $this->model_security->getsecurity();

    $key = $this->input->post('nim');
    $data['nama'] = $this->input->post('nama');
    $data['nim'] = $this->input->post('nim');
    $data['jurusan'] = $this->input->post('jurusan');
    $data['tempat_lahir'] = $this->input->post('tempat_lahir');
    $data['tanggal_lahir'] = $this->input->post('tanggal_lahir');
    $data['alamat'] = $this->input->post('alamat');
    $data['agama'] = $this->input->post('agama');
    $data['kelamin'] = $this->input->post('kelamin');
    $data['angkatan'] = $this->input->post('angkatan');
    $data['status'] = $this->input->post('status');

    $this->load->model('model_anggota');
    $query = $this->model_anggota->getdata($key);
    if($query->num_rows()>0){
      $this->model_anggota->getupdate($key,$data);
      $this->session->set_flashdata('info','Data sukses diupdate');
    }else{
      $this->model_anggota->getinsert($data);
      $this->session->set_flashdata('info','Data sukses disimpan');
    }
    redirect('data_anggota');
  }

  public function delete(){
    $this->model_security->getsecurity();
    $this->load->model('model_anggota');

    $key = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $this->db->where('nim',$key);
    $query = $this->db->get('tb_anggota');
    if($query->num_rows()>0){
      $this->model_anggota->getdelete($key);
      $this->session->set_flashdata('info','Data sukses dihapus');
    }
    redirect('data_anggota');
  }

}
```

Comment: what you want now from us?

Comment: In getdata(), is it `nama` or is it `nim`? Your post name is `nim`.

Comment: @Mr. Blue, thanks, now edit my data work

Comment: is there any error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are getting `nim` value as `$key`, and sending that to check in the `name` column. so, it's returning 0. as per your code, if you the 0 return data will be inserted instead of update. as well as in the update part also, you are checking `nim` value in `name` field.

update your codes like following

```
public function getdata($key){
    $this->db->where('nim',$key);
    $hasil = $this->db->get('tb_anggota');
    return $hasil;
}

public function getupdate($key,$data){
    $this->db->where('nim',$key);
    $this->db->update('tb_anggota',$data);
}
```